# Google Analytics, Count of Sessions

Tags: google-analytics

**EDIT**
This [post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102031/estimate-concurrent-users-per-month-in-google-analytics) indicates that sessions should be interpreted as visitors for that hour.

```
Using the graph to identify which hour has the highest traffic and record 
the number of visitors for that hour
```

---

I am looking at a Google Analytics report (Audience --> Overview) for a website. In section *Audience --> Overview*, I have selected **Sessions vs. Select a metric**.  I have specified a frequency of **Hourly**.

I mouse clicked on a peak and saw

```
Thursday, January 17, 2019 10:00
 Sessions:19,732
```

Is this telling me that I had 19,732 concurrent sessions open at 10:00? Or that in the hour between 9:00 and 10:00, that 19,732 sessions had been opened (and many likely closed)? Please note that

```
Avg. Session Duration = 00:09:07
```

I looked at [How Count of Sessions is calculated](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032796?hl=en) and that leads me to believe that the 19,732 sessions is for the hour between 9:00 and 10:00.

Can someone confirm this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that number would represent how many sessions were started during that hour.

You shouldn't interpret sessions as visitors/users. As one user can have many sessions during that hour. By default, max of 2 (new session at say the 5th minute, no activity, come back at the 35th minute, session 2).

Comment: We don't seem to be collecting Visits. However coming back 35 minutes later counts as load so sessions fits my need. Thank you.

Comment: Correction GA [renamed](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108380651474242506484/posts/TpUEF7ZzqZJ) "Visits" to "Sessions" and "Unique Visitors" to "Users".

Comment: I ended up specifying the Users dimension rather than Sessions. Google Analytics only counts Sessions that start within the hour but counts Users in every hour that they appear. Sessions that started before the start of the hour that then bleeds over into the hour being counted are not counted but Users are.  So Users can give a more accurate count.